# NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains crash

Tags: ios, crash

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x2fc30fec
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3367b788 constructBuffers
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3367af38 _parseComponents
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3367aeb2 _CFURLInit
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3367a64e CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3367a41c _CFCopyHomeDirURLForUser
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3367a3ba CFCopyHomeDirectoryURLForUser
6   Foundation                      0x33f90564 NSHomeDirectoryForUser
7   Foundation                      0x33f906d6 _NSExpandTildeInPath
8   Foundation                      0x33fb16b0 -[NSString(NSPathUtilities) stringByExpandingTildeInPath]
9   Foundation                      0x33fb14c2 NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
10  WenHua                          0x0018844a +[FilePathsManager ServerAddressFileInDocument] (FilePathsManager.m:90)
11  WenHua                          0x00176bcc +[ServerAddress loadServerAdressList:dealArray:] (SeverAdress.m:102)
12  WenHua                          0x0012ebcc -[Adapter randomTradeServer] (Adapter.m:7975)
```

This is the code:

```
 +(NSString *)ServerAddressFileInDocument
    {
        NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        return [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ServerAddress.plist"];
    }

+ (void)loadServerAdressList:(NSMutableArray *)marketArray dealArray:(NSMutableArray *)dealArray 
{ 
      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[FilePathsManager        ServerAddressFileInDocument]]; 
      NSKeyedUnarchiver *unArchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
      [marketArray setArray:[unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"market"]]; 
      [dealArray setArray:[unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"deal"]]; 
      [unArchiver finishDecoding]; [unArchiver release];
 }
```

In this crash report, does it mean app crash at `"NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains"`?
I am not familiar with crash report,thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please post the code, where it is crashing ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your app crashed when running "[FilePathsManager ServerAddressFileInDocument]" at (FilePathsManager.m:90)

Comment: Those path or Directory method addresses seem like something is wrong when excuting NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains,am i right?

Comment: Not sure,your code runs just fine in my project.Try to enable zombie objects and run again,see what you got.

Comment: it runs fine in my phone.But it happens in many customers' iPhones.

Comment: I'm still testing, hope it happens in my phone.

Comment: Since the third parameter of NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains() is "YES",method "-stringByExpandingTildeInPath" is called, maybe something is going wrong when expanding "~" to full path on some of your customers' iPhones.

Comment: I found other reason,a file is wrongly provided by server, so a method recursively call itself.We changed it.I'll see if anyone report crash tomorrow.

Comment: Everything is OK~Thank you~